# Вставить длинный текс в таблицу

Tags: javascript, html

Всем добра.
На могу сообразить как сделать следующее:

1. Имеем длинный текс.
2. имеем таблицу с тремя столбцами.
3. имеем кнопку "Вставить текст".
4. Необходимо вставить длинный текст во второй столбец таблицы, но его необходимо вставить так чтобы первая строка таблицы вмещала только то количество текста сколько позволяет ширина столбца таблица, если текс длиннее этого значения то необходимо добавить новую строку таблицы и остаток текста вставить туда. Добавлять столько строк в таблице на сколько длиннее текст.

Comment: Как вариант, ваш длинный текст разбить на массив с каким количеством символов и далее добавлять

Comment: с помощью text().lenght можно попробовать каждый раз обрезая текст и пересчитывая оставшуюся длину текста заного, в цикле в общем. Писать геморно просто, не хочу)).

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо.